# How to reduce space between two rows of a table of fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have made this table but when there are more than one item in the loop the space between the two elements is too big. How can I reduce the spacing between the two elements?

```html
<table width="100%" height="280" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);empty-cells: hide;">


  <thead>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="80">Sr</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="400">Description of Goods</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="150">HSN</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Qty</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Unit</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Rate (&#x20b9;)</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="150">Amount (&#x20b9;)</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $ctr =0; foreach($datasdetails as $data){ $ctr++; ?>
    <tr>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $ctr; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->itemName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->hsnName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->qty_received,$itemDec[0]->noofdecimal);?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->unitName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->rate,2); ?><br>
        <?php if($datas[0]->price_term==1){$pt="(FOR)";}else if($datas[0]->price_term==2){$pt="(EX)";}else{$pt='';} echo $pt; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->taxable_value,2); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;font-size: 12px;">Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center;">
        <?php echo number_format($datastotal[0]->totalQty,$itemDec[0]->noofdecimal) ; ?>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;">Total</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center;">
        <?php echo number_format($datastotal[0]->totalAmount,2); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: you could try : `tr td, tr th{height:0}
table tfoot::after {content:'';display:table-row;}` ... if you do not want to remove `height="280"`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using fixed height of the table

```
<table width="100%" height="280"
```

Just remover `height="280"`

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;border-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);empty-cells: hide;">


  <thead>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="80">Sr</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="400">Description of Goods</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="150">HSN</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Qty</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Unit</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="130">Rate (&#x20b9;)</th>
    <th style="font-size: 12px;" width="150">Amount (&#x20b9;)</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $ctr =0; foreach($datasdetails as $data){ $ctr++; ?>
    <tr>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $ctr; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->itemName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->hsnName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->qty_received,$itemDec[0]->noofdecimal);?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo $data->unitName; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->rate,2); ?><br>
        <?php if($datas[0]->price_term==1){$pt="(FOR)";}else if($datas[0]->price_term==2){$pt="(EX)";}else{$pt='';} echo $pt; ?>
      </td>
      <td id="t01" style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;">
        <?php echo number_format($data->taxable_value,2); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;font-size: 12px;">Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center;">
        <?php echo number_format($datastotal[0]->totalQty,$itemDec[0]->noofdecimal) ; ?>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;font-size: 12px;">Total</td>
      <td style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center;">
        <?php echo number_format($datastotal[0]->totalAmount,2); ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```